# My Phone isnt working

Tags: battery, hardware

I havent used my LG Volt phone for a couple of months because i bought a ios phone. My ios phone broke and i tried charging my LG Volt phone over night and turning it on no response. I tried taking my battery out and holding power button nothing happened. Tried holding volume down and power button nothing happened. Just a black screen somebdoy help me please.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you get a new battery. Leaving a phone unused for a while drains the battery completely.
Replacing it might be the only solution here.

Good luck!